# Let $N \unlhd G$. Show that $N \unlhd (G'N)$ and $G'N/N=v_N(G')$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $N \unlhd G$. Show that $N \unlhd (G'N)$ and $G'N/N=v_N(G')$.

**Definition :**

$(1)$ $G'$ is only the derived subgroup of G

$(2)$ $v_N$ is simply the natural application of $G'N \to G'N/N$.

I already proved the first part of the problem. The problem statement comes from a book. I think there is a little mistake because the second part should be $G'N/N=v_N(G'N)$. Am I wrong?

Comment: For the second part, I suspect the line of thought is that "$G'$ is enough to get all of $G'N/N$." That is, where does $v_N$ send everything in $G'N \setminus G'$?

Comment: @pjs36 I know by the definition of "derived subgroup" that $v_N$ is an epimorphism, so $G'N/N=v_N(G'N)$. Where do you come with your comment? After thinking about it, I don't see what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Idea**: Things in $G'N$ are products of things in $G'$ with things in the kernel of $v_N$; the $N$ in $G'N$ isn't going to affect $\operatorname{im}(v_N)$ at all. It must be $G'$ alone that's responsible for (i.e., is equal to) $\operatorname{im}(v_N).$

---

**Details** That $v_N$ is an epimorphism means, in particular, that it's surjective: We know that $v_N(G'N) = G'N/N$.

Since $G'N$ consists of products $\{gn : g \in G', n \in N\}$, let's see: what does $v_N$ do to such an element? Well, we have

$$v_N(gn) = v_N(g)\underbrace{v_N(n)}_{= 1} = v_N(g) \in v_N(G').$$

So everything in $G'N$ gets sent, by $v_N$, to something in the image of $G'$ alone. But as you pointed out, $v_N$ is surjective. That means that $G'$ must be sufficient to get all of $\operatorname{im}(v_N)$; that is, $v_N(G') = G'N / N$, as desired.

Comment: So, you're not wrong when you say that $v_N(G'N) = G'N/N$; that's absolutely true. It's just that a *stronger* statement is possible, which is interesting.